# Override ToString of a Null Object? C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

I have a List<> of say People, and people have an instance of a Thought object, I display People in a gridview, there is one column for each variable of the People Class and one for Thoughts, which displays the Thought's class Tostring Override, when I delete a thought, if it was used by any given "People" It would set that People's thought to "null" but when I try to retrieve that "null" from the db (ADO.NET) I get an error (which I think doesn't matter atm), how can I display a "NULL" on the gridview of People in which thoughts have been deleted?

EDIT:
Here is the method I use to save the DATASET:

```
        public List<People> PeopleList()
        {
            ControllerClass cont = new ControllerClass();
            List<People> list = new List<People>();
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM People";
            DataSet data = Select(strSQL);
            if (data.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow Row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    People p = new People();
                    p.IdPeople= Convert.ToInt32(Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
                    p.NamePeople= Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                    p.ThoughtPeople= cont.SearchThought(Convert.ToInt32(Row.ItemArray[3].ToString()));
                    list.Add(p);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

I use a method to search for thoughts because I save the thought's ID as a foreign key

Comment: How are you displaying value in your gridview? Please share your relevant code !

Comment: I just use the List<> as a datasource

Comment: @AkashKC I have added some code that might be of use, not exactly what you asked for

Comment: what about this ? `var thought = cont.SearchThought(Convert.ToInt32(Row.ItemArray[3];` `p.ThoughtPeople= thought != null ? though.ToString() : "NULL"`

Answer (score 0):

Handle it like

```
p.NamePeople= Row.ItemArray[1] == DBNull.Value ? "NULL" : Row.ItemArray[1].ToString():
```